# justify-content and flex-grow being ignored

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a problem with CSS flexbox. I had a working code yesterday yet today when I tested my solution it stopped working for some reason. It has to do with flexbox.

This is the result I want to have:

1. To be able to position the content with `justify-content`. This fails
2. Content should take all the available space so it has `flex-grow: 1`. This fails, as well.
3. The footer should be at the bottom since the content would push it down by taking all the available space thanks to `flex-grow: 1`. This fails.

It seems that whole flexbox stopped working correctly for me.

[image: what I want to have]

I believe the problem is that for some reason flexbox does not even respond correctly to this:

```
`justify-content: flex-start`
```

If I try any other values there like `center`, `flex-end`, etc nothing happens.

Funny thing is that yesterday flexbox was behaving correctly, I could position it around with `justify-content` and today I can't.

What am I missing here why is not at least `justify-content: flex-end` or `justify-content: center` doing behaving correctly and positioning the content?

If I fix the problem that causes `justify-content` to stop working I believe `flex-grow` will also work.

Does anyone have an idea why it's misbehaving?

I can get flex to behaving using this playground so I know my code should be working, My code above is exactly what I did here in the playground:
https://demos.scotch.io/visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-flexbox-playground/demos/

```css
.ikigai {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.header, .footer {
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
}

.content {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ikigai">
  <div class="header">this is a header</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="footer">footer 12</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/re01pn2x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flex container has no height defined.

Therefore, it defaults to `height: auto` (content-driven height).

Add this to your code:

```
.ikigai {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
.ikigai {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* justify-content: flex-start; */ /* default value; not necessary */
  height: 100vh;
}

.header, .footer {
  height: 80px;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* optional; if you don't want items to shrink vertically */
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
}

.content {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* override default margins; prevents vertical scrollbar */
}
```

```html
<div class="ikigai">
  <div class="header">this is a header</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="footer">footer 12</div>
</div>
```

More details: [How to make div 100% height of the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276)

---

**`justify-content`**

Note that `justify-content` wasn't working in your code because there was no free space available. This property works by distributing free space in the container. In this case, because the container was defaulting to `height: auto`, there was only enough space to accommodate the content.

**`justify-content` & `flex-grow`**

Also note that even with a `height` defined that creates extra space, `justify-content` will not work if you use `flex-grow`. Why? Because `flex-grow` will consume that free space, again leaving no space for `justify-content` to distribute.

Comment: Well, the above saved me hours now! Also that extra explanation about flex-grow, you saved me hours and a headache! Thanks! I ended up using min-height: 100vh; if anyone wonders it's better then just height: 100vh which does not work as soon as content becomes too long.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could assist. Yes, `min-height` is a better solution in your case. `height: 100vh` would work in cases where the content element is scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You can fixed using height:100vh;

```
.ikigai {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header, .footer {
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
}

.content {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```